# jmeter with "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" - how to cache after first download for each user?

Tags: caching, jmeter

When a real user hits a site, his browser will download and cache most static imagers.  When he hits another page, any already downloaded resources (images, css, js etc) will be pulled from the cache, maybe after a head call to check it hasnt changed.

In jmeter, if you have a realistic scenario where each user is hitting several pages of your site, I assume that for every page, "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" will download them again for that user, which is a very unrealistic scenario.  Its as if the user has all caching switched off.

Any idea how to simulate real user caching behaviour?

May be even taking into account the resources cache headers, like a real browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) it will represent the browser's cache hence JMeter will not re-download the embedded resources on 2nd iteration (unless you explicitly tell JMeter to do so by ticking `Clear cache each iteration?` box

[image]

as you can see, first occurrence of opening `https://jmeter.apache.org` website results in downloading images, styles and fonts and on the second occurrence these requests are not made.

More information: [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)